# OAuth Server with Android Client

Tags: java, android, oauth-2.0

I would like to implement OAuth authentication for my mobile **Android** users. At the Android part I can solve the problem with opening a **HttpClient**.

The HttpClient would connect to my site, where the OAuth server would run, presenting the providers to login to. The problem is that I don't know what OAuth server to use. I'm looking at open source alternatives, so nothing like **janrain**, etc.

Can you suggest any OAuth servers that would be useful in my configuration I'm describing. There are so many alternatives available (mostly in java, php, django, etc), but are just some projects maintained by a few individuals. That could also work, if the packages are maintained properly.

And I don't need so many oauth providers. I need the following ones: Yahoo, Twitter, Facebook, Google, and that's pretty much it.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

> And I don't need so many oauth providers. I need the following ones: Yahoo, Twitter, Facebook, Google, and that's pretty much it.

In this case why do you need an Auth server at all?

What authorization schema do you plan to use?